# PHP-cURL-Pass the value from POST into URL

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to put an ID into URL before this URL being posted with values. I am not a     programmer so forgive me for my layman description. Here, few values are being posted to this file, that includes an ID which I am getting it using request method like

```
$id = $_REQUEST['abc'];
```

Now I want to attach this value abc to url below before it being processed further. so I want the $url value to be 'http://app.xyz.com/db/abc' before it being process further.

```
$url = 'http://app.xyz.com/db/';    
$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datatopost);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

}

?>

<?php echo $response; ?><br />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd do something like:

```
$id = $_REQUEST['abc'];
$url = 'http://app.xyz.com/db/' . $id;
```

Assuming `$_REQUEST['abc']` contains the string "abc".

Comment: Thank you very much. Got stuck at this for long time, simple thing, could not make it out. Extremely thankful to you for A QUICK RESPONSE.